# Have Word not mark abbreviations as end-of-sentence

Tags: microsoft-word

I have Microsoft Word's rather handy grammar checker on, but if I use an abbreviation or a word like "Yahoo!" Word marks the punctuation as the end of the sentence, and then marks the uncapitalized next word as a grammar error because it thinks that is the start of a sentence. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is only a couple of abbreviations of brand names (Yahoo!) that you keep coming across, then you can add them to the AutoCorrect exceptions for "do not capitalize after:"

In Word 2007 click the **Office Orb button** and choose **Word options** or in 2010 click **File** then **Options**

I'm not sure about 2007 but in 2010 you're looking for the AutoCorrect options under **Proofing**.

[image: Word Auto Correct]

On a side note there should already be a substantial list of abbreviations, assuming they are enabled.

Comment: +1 for a handy hint. I was going to answer "no, because Word doesn't know the difference between a normal punctuation mark and something part of a trademark" but this makes sense.

Comment: It almost works. It will not let me add "Yahoo!"; I assume this is because of the exclamation point. (I'm using Word for Mac 2011, if that helps anyone assess the situation.) I did not know about this feature of Word, though. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I reckon I don't use Yahoo! too often to care about the above comment. Thanks for showing this!